# How can I get ID from "ul" dynamic tag

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have the next situation.
I have a button in HTML code. When I press one of the options from the button I call a function that constructs the content from other button.

I have a ul tag in HTML code with a list of li tags inside. The value of this li tags are generated dynamically with a query database.
When I generate the options from li tags I assign a different ID to each other.
Here you can see the code that I have for the second button:

```
<div class="dropdown" class="btn-group-lg" id="test">
<button name="selSensor" id="seltipoSensor" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-
toggle" type="submit" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <span>Select one option</span>
 </button>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="test2">
</ul>
</div>
```

Here you can see the code that I have to generate the li tags inside the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function selectedUbi(ubicacion){
  var datos = {
    "arg" : ubicacion
  };
  $.ajax({
    data:  datos,
    url:   'condatabase/calculos_bdd2.php',
    type:  'post',
    success:  function (response) {
        if(response){
            document.getElementById("test2").innerHTML = "";
            var ul = document.getElementById("test2");
            for (i=0;i<response.length;i++){
                var li = document.createElement("li");
                li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(response[i][i+1]));
                li.setAttribute("id", "element"+i);
                li.setAttribute("onclick",myFunction);
                ul.appendChild(li);
            }
        }
    },
    dataType:"json"
    });
}
</script>
```

The question that I have is...
how can I get the ID from the li tag that I generate dynamically?

I tried to use "getElementByID" and "getElementByTagName" but as the ID is dynamic I have no idea to caught the value.

For example the button have the next options to select:
- apple (ID= element0)
- bannana (ID= element1)
- carrot (ID= element2)

When I select the option "bannana" I need to get the ID "element1".

Comment: Two things. First, where's your code for `myFunction`? Second, if you're using jQuery, why aren't you *using* jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [querySelectorAll](http://devdocs.io/dom/element/queryselectorall) on your container to get a list of elements and then read their attribute id.

```
function getIds(container){
  return [...container.querySelectorAll('li[id]')].map(li => li.getAttribute('id'));
}
```

However, I would rather recommend to create a data layer abstraction to handle operations related to data fetching, etc... in order to avoid a strong coupling on your html structure and your "logic" code.

```
function createStore(){
   return {
     async fetch(arg){ /*... return your data (and cache it etc */ }
   };
}
```

so your button handlers can share that "store"

```
const store = createStore();

document.getElementBy('button1').addEventListener('click', () => {
   store.fetch().then(data => { /* do something with your data like updating html ... */})
});

document.getElementBy('button2').addEventListener('click', () => {
   store.fetch().then(data => { /* do something with your data like updating html ... */})
});

//etc
```